# RTABMAP localization with turtlebot issue

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, turtlebot, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

As instructed in the tutorial [Mapping and Navigation with Turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot) after mapping "`$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch args:="--delete_db_on_start" rgbd_odometry:=true`"

for localization when i try to execute the command " `$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch localization:=true`" .

i get following error:

```
[ INFO] [1454339969.590369016]: rtabmap 0.10.10 started...

[ INFO] [1454339970.864339986]: Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.

[ WARN] [1454339972.332150185]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_footprint' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.. canTransform returned after 0.100846 timeout was 0.1.

[ WARN] [1454339974.865176406]: rtabmap: Could not get transform from odom to base_footprint after 0.100000 second!

[ WARN] [1454339974.995544194]: rtabmap: Could not get transform from odom to base_footprint after 0.100000 second!
```

and this goes on....

what's the issue? please guide me i am new to ROS.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225559/rtabmap-localization-with-turtlebot-issue/) by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-02-02**:
Error missing?

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2016-02-03**:
due to some reason the error message is not shown here. do u know why?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-02-03**:
sorry no, maybe try pastebin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

On your second call, the visual odometry node is not started, so it is why rtabmap is complaining that there is no odometry TF between `/odom` and `/base_footprint`. Try this instead:

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch localization:=true rgbd_odometry:=true
```

Note that if you are on the actual robot, you may want to use the odometry TF/topic from turtlebot.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2016-02-21**:
Thanks! that worked.But after done with mapping, when i proceeded for localization and typed  the command as mentioned above by you and in http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot localization mode, nothing happens, as mentioned in the link a 2d map should reappear.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-02-22**:
On the tutorial it is stated "the 2D map would re-appear again **when a loop closure is found**", so maybe no loop closure could be found (are there warnings on the console?). The map may be too small.